# How can I declare an extern reference to a variable of type char** in Chapel?

Tags: chapel

I'm trying to reference the C `char **environ`, but I can't figure out how to declare the variable in Chapel.  I've tried a few things, but the compiler generates code that the backend compiler won't compile due to a type mismatch.

Even just trying to get something to writeln:

`extern var environ: c_ptr(c_string);
writeln(environ);`

`c_ptr(c_string)` generates a C var of type `const char**`.

`c_ptr(c_ptr(c_char))` one of type `signed char **`

`c_ptr(c_ptr(c_uchar))` a `unsigned char **`.

`c_ptr(c_void_ptr)` a `void**`

And all of these are incompatible with the `char **environ`.  How can I get at the contents of this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really an integration issue with C (since the Chapel compiler currently produces C code by default) and represents a place where there's just an impedance mismatch between C's type system and Chapel's.

Just for fun, let's write this program using an extern block and the LLVM backend.

```
// env.chpl
extern {
  extern char** environ;
}

writeln(environ);
```

Now we'll compile and run it:

```
chpl env.chpl  --llvm
./env
```

and it outputs a pointer address. See? it's a C issue.

If you want to continue using the C backend, you'll have to do something like this:

```
// env.chpl
require "c-environ.h";
extern var environ: c_ptr(c_ptr(c_char));
writeln(environ);
```

with this C support file (which is needed unless you find a standard C header that defines environ):

```
// c-environ.h
extern char **environ;
```

Compile that one with

```
chpl env.chpl --ccflags -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types
```

and it works similarly to the version using the LLVM backend. (And, if you don't add -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types, you should see a *warning* from the C compiler and the program can still run. Note that --devel / CHPL_DEVELOPER=1 will turn on warnings-are-errors from the C compiler).

It's probably worth creating an issue on the Chapel project and/or filing a bug with GCC/whatever C compiler you are using about this, though. The Chapel compiler adds `-Wno-pointer-sign` to GCC (which you can see with `chpl env.chpl --print-commands`) and perhaps needs to be also throwing `-Wno-incompatible-pointer-types`. But, I'm surprised in this case that `-Wno-pointer-sign` is not sufficient to squelch the warning from GCC.

Comment: Actually, there is already a Chapel issue about a related problem: https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/7983

Comment: WRT `-Wno-pointer-sign`, I suspect gcc sees a difference between the difference between `char *` vs `unsigned char *` and `char **` vs `unsigned char **` -- the latter are two pointers to pointers, and the pointed-to pointers aren't objects that differ in signedness.